# How can I run a terminal command asynchronously using Python?

Tags: python, linux, asynchronous, bluetooth, subprocess

I am working on a Linux environment, trying to automate these 2 Linux commands using a Python script:

1. **sudo rfcomm connect 0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX**
2. **hcitool rssi XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX**

Command 1 connects to my bluetooth device, and command 2 returns the received signal strength inidication (RSSI) as long as the device is connected. So the script must be able to connect and then extract RSSI without any human intervention. I am running these commands using the *subprocess* module.

**The problem:** When command 1 is run such that a connection is made, it says "*Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX on channel 1
Press CTRL-C for hangup*", **however it does not return.** It only returns once the connection is lost, at which point it would be impossible to extract RSSI. Currently the python script does not continue to the next line of code after running command 1, so I am unable to run command 2 afterwards. Here is my code:

```py
def get_rssi(): 
    while True:
        p1 = subprocess.run(['hcitool', 'rssi', shimmer_id], capture_output=True, text=True)
        
        if p1.stderr:
            print('stderr:', p1.stderr)
            reconnect()
        if p1.stdout:
            print('stdout:', p1.stdout)
            time.sleep(0.3)


def reconnect():
    reconnected = False
    print('[-] lost connection, reconnecting...')
    
    while reconnected is False:
        p2 = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'rfcomm', 'connect', '0', shimmer_id], capture_output=True, text=True)
        
# If the connection on the previous line is successful, nothing is executed from  here onward! The script only continues once the above line returns (i.e. when the connection is lost)

        if p2.stderr:
            if 'Host is down' in p2.stderr.decode():
                print('Host is down')
                time.sleep(0.3)
                reconnect()
        else:
            reconnected = True
            
    get_rssi()
```

I have tried threading and multiprocessing, but they do not help since command 1 never "joins" in python threading lingo. I am aware that I probably need to run command 1 **asynchronously**, but I am struggling to implement it properly in python even while referring to the asyncio docs. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can certainly do this with threading.  By using daemon mode, the thread is detached, and you don't have to join it.  However, you can also use `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell`.

Comment: I wish to know when it returns, because I also need to know when the connection has failed (out of range). What method do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make an RFCOMM connection.

Both `rfcomm` and `hcitool` have been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) by the BlueZ project back in 2017 so I wouldn't recommend starting a project using these.

BlueZ has APIs that are designed to be accessed from languages like Python and these are documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc and the official examples are at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

However, RFCOMM (or Serial Port Profile) connections can be done with the socket library in the standard Python releases. There are examples at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382835/7721752

There are also examples in the above answer of using the [Bluedot](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothclient) library to do the same.